# onPartialSend not working in surveyjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, redux, surveyjs

I have implemented survey app using **react**, **redux** and **[surveyjs](https://github.com/surveyjs/surveyjs)**    library. I am using firebase to host my database.I have tried to    store the survey data in each step using the onPartialSend event on    Survey model.

However the redux and updating on the firebase works    well but the navigation to the next page in survey does not work! if    I comment the dispatch part of redux action, the navigation works    fine, otherwise it doesn't.

you can see the issue in the following like! 
[Surveyjs issue in github](https://github.com/surveyjs/surveyjs/issues/426#issuecomment-305952467)

I am wondering if anyone faced this issue? 
Thanks!